# What would I use to distribute power in my project?

Tags: current, servo, breadboard

I want to power 10 SG90 servos, which each operate at 4.8v or 6v and need over 1 amp in order to start and use 700ma max during operation (I think). When I look at a kit like this ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B073ZC68QG/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073ZC68QG)) on Amazon, it says one of the questions is as follows:

Question:What is the maximum current rating on the power supply module?

Answer:The Power Supply Module Maximum Output Current: < 700ma

Does that mean each servo will only get under 700ma and not be able to start? If so, what tool should I use to distribute power to parts in my robot?

Comment: stationary, or mobile robot?  I couldn't find that quote on that link.

Comment: the robot itself will not move, but it will have 10 moving servos as part of a robotic hand.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at 10 suitable relays,or solid state devices, rated for the task.

Then I would be sourcing a power supply that can deliver 4.8V or 6V at the max load ie that would be assuming all 10 starting at the same time as you always consider the worst or most difficult scenario.

Comment: Could you provide any links where I could buy such items? Also, is there no need for a power distribution board of some kind?

Comment: @nothing please don’t make this into a shopping question as they are off-topic as per the faq and help files, if you have not read them then please do.

Comment: theses are servos not solenoids they include inbuilt drivers and just require a 5V supply  and a PWM signal.

Answer (score 0):

For your power suipply look for a 50 to 60W desktop power supply.

eg: https://nz.rs-online.com/web/p/desktop-power-supplies/2008934/

Shop around, that price isn't particularly good.

depending on how many servos are active at any time a less powerful power supply may work.